# Repetitive output in IF statement

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to print out the date if the below conditions are met, but I kept getting repeat dates. I figured the problem is in

if df['Close'][i+1]<df['Open'][i+1] and df['Close'][i+2]<df['Open'][i]:

but I don't understand why.

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

---

Code:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)-2):        
    if df['Close'][i]>df['Open'][i]:
        if df['Close'][i+1]<df['Open'][i+1] and df['Close'][i+2]<df['Open'][i]:
            print df.index[i]
```

---

Output:

```
[Timestamp('2019-07-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-07-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-09-21 00:00:00'), etc...]
```

---

Sample DF:

```
            Open       High         Low         Close       Adj             
Date                        
2019-06-03  136.798004  137.110992  136.615997  136.761002  136.761002  
2019-06-04  136.822006  137.457993  136.539993  136.791000  136.791000  
2019-06-05  137.479004  137.757996  137.199997  137.490005  137.490005  
2019-06-06  137.438995  137.733002  136.970001  137.436996  137.436996  
2019-06-07  137.690002  138.164993  137.492996  137.688995  137.688995
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using pandas, why not doing it in the vectorized way?

```
df.index[df['Close'].shift(-2) < df["Open"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range(len(df.index)-1):`
The problem is here. You loop is running till 2nd last index. So in this condition `df['Close'][i+2]<df['Open'][i]`, when `i= 2nd last index, i+2 goes out of range. Hence, the error.

Try changing the range, e.g: `for i in range(len(df.index)-2)`  and it should work fine for you.

Comment: Sorry, but the problem is the repetition. I accidentally typed -1 here, but in my code i did indeed type index-2. So the repetition still exists

Answer (score 0):

I realised the repetition was justified, as the output was for different sets of input. Thanks for replying!